# How to create YYYY/MM/DD folder dynamically in Copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I was trying to create a pipeline that copy data from S3 to Azure ADLS. And the I tried to create yyyy/mm/dd folder dynamically in Copy activity.

Like this:

```
@concat(
  pipeline().parameters.target,
  formatDateTime(utcNow(),’yyyy’,’/‘,
  formatDateTime(utcNow(),’MM’,’/‘,
  formatDateTime(utcNow(),’dd’),’/‘,
)
```

I got an error “the pipeline run failed due to an activity failure. Please check the activity grid below for more detailed information”
Copy data for each activity fails.

Comment: It looks like your syntax might not be correct, you need to close the parentheses on the `formatDateTime()` functions. You should also be able to do it with a single call like this: `formatDateTime(utcNow(), '/yyyy/MM/dd/')` which would simplify your expression significantly.

Comment: Could you share the error message in the copy activity?

Answer (score 1):

- The expression has errors in it. Closing parenthesis are missing in the formatDateTime function.

**Corrected expression:**

```
@concat(
pipeline().parameters.target,
formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy'),'/',
formatDateTime(utcNow(),'MM'),'/',
formatDateTime(utcNow(),'dd'),'/'
)
```

You can also use the simplified expression as suggested by community member in comments.

```
@concat(
pipeline().parameters.target,formatDateTime(utcNow(), '/yyyy/MM/dd/')
```

- You cannot use the pipeline parameter in the folder path.

> Pipeline parameters can only be used within their defining pipeline. Define dataset parameters to accept the pipeline parameter values instead.

[image]

- Instead, you can create a dataset parameter for folder. Give the above expression as the value for dataset parameter.

[image: gif1]

- When expression is given like this in dataset parameter, pipeline is executed without error.

Answer (score 0):

**date +'%Y%m%d'** : 20230830 --> try this and this will create folder with date(current date) dynamically in S3. Change the format according to you.